Proving that if it is Dirac measure, then it is invariant.
I was reading this question here:
Show that the only $f$- invariant probability measure is the delta measure at $0.$
And from my understanding, the meaning of "prove that the only invariant measure on $D$ is the Dirac measure" is that the question is asking to prove two parts, which are:
$(a)$ If the given measure is $f$-invariant, then it is the Dirac measure.
$(b)$ If the given measure is the Dirac measure, then it is $f$-invariant.
My questions are:
The solution there contains a very good approach to the solution, but there were some missing details, which is the proof of part $(b)$ above, and the proof in part $(a),$ that what we get is actually a Dirac measure (I think it might be a trivial thing but it should be done I think). My question is how to prove part $(b)$?
Also, even if it looks like it is trivial, but since I am self studying this, it might be helpful for me, to see in $(a),$ the proof that what the author get there is actually a Dirac measure, i.e.,  \documentclass{article}
[
\delta_x(U)= \left{
\begin{array}{ll}
1 & x \in U \
0 & x\notin U\
\end{array}
\right.
]
Can someone show me this please?
Here is the solution I am speaking about:
Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $X$ and suppose that $\mu$ is $f$-invariant.
By Poincare recurrence, for any Borel set $E\subset X$, we have that
$$\mu\bigg(\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty\bigcap_{n\ge N}\{x\in E: f^n(x)\not\in E\}\bigg)=0$$
Let $r\in\mathbb{N}$ and set $E_r:=\{x\in X: |x|\ge \frac{1}{r}\}$. Note that $\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty\bigcap_{n\ge N}\{x\in E_r: f^n(x)\not\in E_r\}=E_r$ ( indeed, for $x\in E_r$ we have $f^n(x)\to0$, so there is some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|f^n(x)|<1/r$ for all $n\ge N$). Therefore
$$\mu(E_r)=\mu\bigg(\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty\bigcap_{n\ge N}\{x \in E_r: f^n(x)\not\in E_r\}\bigg)=0$$
Now $X\setminus\{0\}=\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{N}}E_r$, so $\mu(X\setminus\{0\})=0$, i.e. $\mu(\{0\})=1$, i.e. $\mu$ is the Dirac mass at $0$.

For part $(a)$ the Dirac measure $\delta$ is equivalently the only measure such that $\mu(\{0\})=1$ and $\mu(X\setminus \{0\})=0$.
For part $(b)$, the measure $\mu=f_*\delta$ is such that $\mu(E)=\delta(f^{-1}(E))=\delta(E)$ where the last step follows from the fact that $0\in E\iff 0\in f^{-1}(E)$.
A lighter proof is the following: let $B_r$ be the open ball centered at $0$ with radius $r$, then $f^{-1}(B_r)=B_{\sqrt{r}}$, which means that for $f$-invariant measure $\mu$ we have $\mu(B_r)=\mu(B_{\sqrt r})$. Then for a fixed $0<r<1$ we have $\mu(B_{r^{1/2^k}})$ equal for all integer $k$. Their union is all $X$, so by continuity all these balls have measure $1$. Moreover their intersection is $\{0\}$, so $\mu(\{0\})=1$ again by continuity, which implies that $\mu=\delta$.
